# ¿cómo puedo comparar si existen registros?

Tags: php

lo que quiero hacer es que al verificar que haya un registro que coincida con mi consulta me redireccione a otra pagina, el problema es que aunque ingrese un registro que se que existe me regresa el valor 0, cuando según yo, debería ser 1 y me debería redireccionar a otra pagina. 
No tengo claro que estoy haciendo mal.
Este es el código:

```php
<?php
//conectar a la base de datos
include('conexion.php');

$nom = isset($_POST['nombre']);
$contra = isset($_POST['contraseña']);
$result =mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre = '$nom' AND contraseña='$contra'");

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($result);
var_dump($filas);
if ($filas==0) {
    echo"Usuario no encontrado";
}elseif($filas==1){

    header("location: /flamestore/pagina-principal/pagina-principal.php");


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

el error por lo que veo lo tienes en las variables `$nom` y `$contra`, por que solo estas comprobando que existe y no estas recogiendo el valor.

Hice un ejemplo para que puedas probarlo tu mismo.

Lo único que hice es recoger el dato de `$_POST` y cambiar la parte del if, que si tienes al menos un resultado simplemente, te redirecciona.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');

$nom = $_POST['nombre'];
$contra = $_POST['contraseña'];

$result = mysqli_query(
    $conexion,
    "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre = '$nom' AND contraseña='$contra'"
);

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($filas > 0) {
    header("location: /flamestore/pagina-principal/pagina-principal.php");
}

echo "Usuario no encontrado";

?>
```

(Es recomendable no usar letras con diéresis como la "ñ" o caracteres especiales en nombres de variables, campos o nombre de campo de tablas)